# Giving OVZ containers their own IP

Tags: networking, virtualization, openvz

Is it possible to give an OVZ container its own external IPv4 address?

Say I hire a dedicated server and purchase extra IP addresses. Can I assign those extra IPs to the containers?

If so how would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

As long as the additional addresses are on the same subnet as your host IP you can set up a **bridge** interface. Add your physical interface and the OVZ guest's virtual interface as bridge members. Move the IP of the host to the bridge interface instead of the physical interface. Assign the OVZ guest's IP to the virtual interface inside the guest.

There are bridge examples for several distros here: http://xmodulo.com/2013/04/how-to-configure-linux-bridge-interface.html

Comment: This URL from the OpenVZ project has what you need too: https://openvz.org/Common_Networking_HOWTOs

Comment: So I create a bridge with the first tutorial, then use ```vzctl set 101 --ipadd "the new external ip" --save``` for every container?